# Android Spinner and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I am trying to create an app that has 2 spinners. the First spinner would have a selection of 1,2,3. If the the selected value of the first spinner is 1 then the second spinner would have a value of a,b,c. If the selected value of the first spinner is 2 then the second would have d,e,f. If 1st = 3 then 2nd = g,h,i. I have created this with this code:

```
String[] categoryValues = new String[] { "1", "2", "3"};
String[] endurance = new String[] { "a", "b", "c"};
String[] strength = new String[] { "d", "e", "f"};
String[] balance = new String[] { "g", "h", "i"};

Spinner exercise = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.exerciseS);
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int     position, long id) {
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(position == 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < endurance.length; ++i) {
            list.add(endurance[i]);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterFT = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        exercise.setAdapter(adapterFT);
        adapterFT.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else if(position == 1){
        for (int i = 0; i < strength.length; ++i) {
            list.add(strength[i]);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDST = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        exercise.setAdapter(adapterDST);
        adapterDST.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else if(position == 2){
        for (int i = 0; i < balance.length; ++i) {
            list.add(balance[i]);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterDST = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        exercise.setAdapter(adapterDST);
        adapterDST.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise_picker);

    Spinner category = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.categoryS);

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < categoryValues.length; ++i) {
        list.add(categoryValues[i]);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    category.setAdapter(adapter);
    category.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


}
```

The problem I am having is that how do I get the value of the second spinner to change a fragment without any buttons(without clicking any buttons)?[layout image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW1Cu.png)

1st spinner = category
2nd spinner = exercise

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do the same as in the 1st spinner and add an onItemSelected listener? On that listener you would create or update the fragment based on what the user selected.

Comment: Do I need to create another onItemSelected listener?

Comment: you can create a new one, or use the existing one and distinguish based on view. But I find it cleaner to have a separate listener.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I should create another one?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.
On First Spinner OnItemSelected() call a method and pass the select item from first spinner in that method just load the second with appropriate item and call setSelected if u want to select particular value in second spinner

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your questions very well but this is what I make out of. I recreated a solution. Check if it fits your need. You can ask question if it needs adjustment.

in `strings.xml`, I created these array  strings

First array string

```
<string-array name="first_spinner">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

Second array string

```
<string-array name="second_spinner">
    <item>a,b,c</item>
    <item>d,e,f</item>
    <item>g,h,i</item>
</string-array>
```

I added two Spinner widgets in the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.inducesmile.myapplication4.MainActivity">


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/first_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Spinner>


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/second_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/first_spinner"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Spinner>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the Activity page, I used this code. I used the stored array to get the selected content in Spinner b as shown

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner firstSpinner;
private Spinner secondSpinner;

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    firstSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.first_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> firstAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.first_spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    firstAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    firstSpinner.setAdapter(firstAdapter);

    secondSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.second_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> secondAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.second_spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    secondAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    secondSpinner.setAdapter(secondAdapter);

    firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            secondSpinner.setSelection(position);

            String[] secondSpinnerContent = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.second_spinner);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Value " + secondSpinnerContent[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    DefaultFragment firstFragment = new DefaultFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.first_container, firstFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    DefaultFragment secondFragment = new DefaultFragment();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.first_container, secondFragment).commit();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have question.

Comment: The options on the second spinner are dependent on the value selected on the first spinner. The fragment's contents are dependent on the second spinner. Yours only changes the fragments. Mine only changes the second spinner value. I want to change the fragments contents when either spinner gets changed. Have you checked the layouts I included? It might help on understanding the question.

Comment: Well, I give you a pointer to your problem but it seem I didn't understand what you need. According to your example, the mapping in spinner a and b is linear eg 1 = a, b, c. if it is like this then they have the same index. You can use the position in spinner a to access the content of array in b. May be you did not understand my solution.